# 'Migrations' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm doing a ASP.NET Core project.
I've installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` NuGet packages.

I ran `Add-Migration InitialCreate` command,
Which created `Migrations` folder and `20180905180349_InitialCreate.cs` file.

But it says

> The type or namespace name 'Migrations' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

What is the cause of this error. Do i need to install any other package ?

Comment: Did you add a reference in your project? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: Add a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.All to your project.  This will be more than you need but will include EntityFramework Core.

Comment: @DCCoder I've included `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" />` in my .csproj file. It seems to fix the issue. But does it add unnecessary packages to my project ?

Comment: use `dotnet ef` cli tools instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Comment: @B45i It will be adding a few unnecessary packages to your project but depending on your needs I highly doubt it will negatively effect you.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Ok, I will show you the minimal setup required for EF Core + Migrations:

You will need to install Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core,  but it is better that instead of that package you first install a EF Core provider for the database you will use. Then that EF Core provider will pull in all the required dependencies ( including Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core ) .

So (for example) for SQLServer db, in the Package Manager Console I will install:

1. **Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**
2. **Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** (for powershell commands)
3. **Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design** (contains migrations engine - and **important** note this package has to be **inside executable project**)

And that's it.

Comment: You would think microsoft would bundle this in with the EntityFramwork.core package

Comment: I had to add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational too.

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational is where the OP's needed namespaces and classes actually are, at least in .NET6.

Answer (score 5):

I faced a similar issue and found that I haven't installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. Initially, I have installed only `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`.

After installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` problem gets resolved

Answer (score 2):

Including "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" was the answer to my problem.